# Comportamento do Math.Round

Tags: .net, vb.net

tenho um projeto em VB.Net que utilizo a Função Round, porém veja o comportamento estranho:

```vbnet
System.Console.WriteLine(math.round(32.625,2)) '32.62
System.Console.WriteLine(math.round(32.635,2)) '32.64
System.Console.WriteLine(math.round(32.645,2)) '32.65

system.console.writeLine(math.round(21.525,2)) '21.52
System.Console.WriteLine(math.round(21.535,2)) '21.54
System.Console.WriteLine(math.round(21.545,2)) '21.54
```

Alguém sabe o motivo?

[image]

Comment: A culpa é da imprecisão dos Doubles. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#rounding-and-precision

Comment: Esse valor 32.635 internamente equivale a 32.634998321533203125.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835001/what-is-wrong-with-math-round-in-vb-net
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969674/net-rounding-issue